# How do you force a non-retina image when using lockFocus on an NSImage?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have the following code to create an image of a circle of 200x200 pixels. This isn't for on-screen usage, so I've manually added an NSBitmapImageRep to the image before locking the focus and drawing.

```
let ovalSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
let ovalPath = NSBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: ovalSize))
let ovalImage = NSImage(size: ovalSize)
let imageRep = NSBitmapImageRep(bitmapDataPlanes: nil, pixelsWide: 200, pixelsHigh: 200, bitsPerSample: 8, samplesPerPixel: 4, hasAlpha: true, isPlanar: true, colorSpaceName: .deviceRGB, bitmapFormat: [.alphaFirst, .thirtyTwoBitLittleEndian], bytesPerRow: 0, bitsPerPixel: 0)
ovalImage.addRepresentation(imageRep!)
ovalImage.lockFocus()
NSColor(deviceWhite: 1, alpha: 1).setFill()
ovalPath.fill()
ovalImage.unlockFocus()
```

However if I Quick Look at `ovalImage` it has been rendered at 400x400, and printing the representations of `ovalImage` produces the following:

```
[<NSCGImageSnapshotRep:0x60000175bf00 cgImage=<CGImage 0x101612d30> (DP)
<<CGColorSpace 0x60000260cba0> (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelRGB; Color LCD)>
    width = 400, height = 400, bpc = 8, bpp = 32, row bytes = 1600 
    kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGImageByteOrder32Little  | kCGImagePixelFormatPacked 
    is mask? No, has masking color? No, has soft mask? No, has matte? No, should interpolate? Yes>]
```

The docs for `lockFocus` mention that a representation will be added if one isn't available, so I'm confused as to why the one I'm adding is being replaced?

Comment: Not an answer, as such, but you can create an `NSGraphicsContext` directly from an `NSBitmapImageRep`, make it current, and draw to the bitmap image rep directly.

Comment: Thanks @KenThomases that seems like a good alternative route if needed 

Comment: My guess: Your screen is a RetinaScreen. My hint1: avoid lockFocus/unLockFocus whenever you can! My hint2: Do what @KenThomases said, he is right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is ["Drawing Offscreen Images Using a Block-Based Drawing Method to Support High Resolution Displays"](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Images/Images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH208-SW37).

You can do this:

```
let ovalPath = NSBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: NSMakeSize(200, 200)))
let ovalImage = NSImage(size: NSMakeSize(200, 200), flipped: false) { (rect) -> Bool in
    NSColor(deviceWhite: 1, alpha: 1).setFill()
    ovalPath.fill()
    return true
}
```

or

```
let ovalSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
let ovalPath = NSBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: NSMakeSize(200, 200)))
let imageRep = NSBitmapImageRep(bitmapDataPlanes: nil, pixelsWide: 200, pixelsHigh: 200, bitsPerSample: 8, samplesPerPixel: 4, hasAlpha: true, isPlanar: true, colorSpaceName: .deviceRGB, bitmapFormat: [.alphaFirst, .thirtyTwoBitLittleEndian], bytesPerRow: 0, bitsPerPixel: 0)
NSGraphicsContext.saveGraphicsState()
NSGraphicsContext.current = NSGraphicsContext(bitmapImageRep: imageRep!)
NSColor(deviceWhite: 1, alpha: 1).setFill()
ovalPath.fill()
NSGraphicsContext.restoreGraphicsState()
let ovalImage = NSImage(size: ovalSize)
ovalImage.addRepresentation(imageRep!)
```

I didn't know the reason why the representation you are adding is being replaced, but you should [treat NSImage and its image representations as immutable objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Images/Images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH208-SW19).

Comment: Thanks, the second solution here was perfect.